# Golang and google api - post request syntax while using oauth for devices status update

Tags: go, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-go-client

I am trying to change the status of the chromeos device.

My "get" request works with getting the device ID from the serial number.

However, I am not able to figure out `how to pass the payload` in golang google sdk/api, since it is a "post" request.

The payload in this case is the Action. (deprovision, disable, reenable, pre_provisioned_disable, pre_provisioned_reenable) and deprovisionReason if action is deprovision.

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/chromeosdevices/action#ChromeOsDeviceAction

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "encoding/csv"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"

    "golang.org/x/oauth2"
    "golang.org/x/oauth2/google"
    admin "google.golang.org/api/admin/directory/v1"
    "google.golang.org/api/option"
)

func readCsvFile(filePath string) [][]string {
    f, err := os.Open(filePath)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Unable to read input file "+filePath, err)
    }
    defer f.Close()

    csvReader := csv.NewReader(f)
    records, err := csvReader.ReadAll()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Unable to parse file as CSV for "+filePath, err)
    }

    return records
}

// Retrieve a token, saves the token, then returns the generated client.
func getClient(config *oauth2.Config) *http.Client {
    // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    // created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    // time.
    tokFile := "token.json"
    tok, err := tokenFromFile(tokFile)
    if err != nil {
        tok = getTokenFromWeb(config)
        saveToken(tokFile, tok)
    }
    return config.Client(context.Background(), tok)
}

// Request a token from the web, then returns the retrieved token.
func getTokenFromWeb(config *oauth2.Config) *oauth2.Token {
    authURL := config.AuthCodeURL("state-token", oauth2.AccessTypeOffline)
    fmt.Printf("Go to the following link in your browser then type the "+
        "authorization code: \n%v\n", authURL)

    var authCode string
    if _, err := fmt.Scan(&authCode); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to read authorization code: %v", err)
    }

    tok, err := config.Exchange(context.TODO(), authCode)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to retrieve token from web: %v", err)
    }
    return tok
}

// Retrieves a token from a local file.
func tokenFromFile(file string) (*oauth2.Token, error) {
    f, err := os.Open(file)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer f.Close()
    tok := &oauth2.Token{}
    err = json.NewDecoder(f).Decode(tok)
    return tok, err
}

// Saves a token to a file path.
func saveToken(path string, token *oauth2.Token) {
    fmt.Printf("Saving credential file to: %s\n", path)
    f, err := os.OpenFile(path, os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE|os.O_TRUNC, 0600)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to cache oauth token: %v", err)
    }
    defer f.Close()
    json.NewEncoder(f).Encode(token)
}

func findDeviceId(srv *admin.Service, deviceSerial string) (deviceId string) {

    deviceId = ""
    r, err := srv.Chromeosdevices.List("aaa").Query(deviceSerial).Do()
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Unable to retrieve device with serial %s in domain: %v", deviceSerial, err)
    } else {
        for _, u := range r.Chromeosdevices {
            deviceId = u.DeviceId
            fmt.Printf("%s %s (%s)\n", u.DeviceId, u.SerialNumber, u.Status)
        }
    }
    return deviceId
}

func main() {

    ctx := context.Background()
    b, err := os.ReadFile("credentials.json")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to read client secret file: %v", err)
    }

    config, err := google.ConfigFromJSON(b, admin.AdminDirectoryDeviceChromeosScope)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to parse client secret file to config: %v", err)
    }
    client := getClient(config)

    srv, err := admin.NewService(ctx, option.WithHTTPClient(client))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to retrieve directory Client %v", err)
    }
    deviceId := findDeviceId(srv, "xxx")

    deviceAction := make(map[string]string)
    deviceAction["action"] = "disable"
    deviceAction["deprovisionReason"] = "retiring_device"

    r, err := srv.Chromeosdevices.Action("aaa", deviceId, &deviceAction).Do()
    fmt.Println(r)
    fmt.Println(err)

}
```

Getting error

```
cannot use deviceAction (variable of type map[string]string) as *admin.ChromeOsDeviceAction value in argument to srv.Chromeosdevices.ActioncompilerIncompatibleAssign
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method [`ChromeosdevicesService.Action`](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/api/admin/directory/v1#ChromeosdevicesService.Action) takes [`ChromeOsDeviceAction`](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/api/admin/directory/v1#ChromeOsDeviceAction):

```
chromeosdeviceaction := &admin.ChromeOsDeviceAction{
    Action: "disable",
    DeprovisionReason: "retiring_device",
}
```

Your code would be simpler and more portable using Application Default Credentials. This approach is shown and referenced in the library's documentation: [Creating a client](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/api/admin/directory/v1#hdr-Creating_a_client)